# Use log4net with separate config file

Tags: c#, log4net

my AssemblyInfo.cs:

```
[assembly: log4net.Config.XmlConfigurator(ConfigFile = "Log4Net.config", Watch = true)]
```

i change the structure just like you said

```
(i just change the <file value="..\Logs\\CurrentLog" /> to <file value="D:\Log\Log.txt" />):

<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<log4net>
  <root>
    <level value="ALL" />
    <appender-ref ref="RollingFileAppender"/>
  </root>
  <appender name="RollingLogFileAppender"  type="log4net.Appender.RollingFileAppender">
    <file value="D:\Log\Log.txt" />
    <appendToFile value="true" />
    <datePattern value="yyyyMMdd" />

    <rollingStyle value="Date" />
    <filter type="log4net.Filter.LevelRangeFilter">
      <acceptOnMatch value="true" />

      <levelMin value="INFO" />
      <levelMax value="FATAL" />
    </filter>

    <layout type="log4net.Layout.PatternLayout">
      <conversionPattern
      value="%-5p %d %5rms %-22.22c{1} %-18.18M - %m%n" />
    </layout>
  </appender>
</log4net>
```

and define the log:

```
private static readonly ILog Log = LogManager.GetLogger("Logger");
```

but still the log.txt file doesn't created yet!

Comment: _"where is the problem?"_ - you didn't read [How do I ask a good question?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). Explain what "doesn't work" and what you have tried to resolve that.

Comment: As said by @CodeCaster, you need to be more specific about the concrete problem. Compilation error? Crash at runtime? The .log file is created?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's something missing in your config file.

```
<log4net>
  <logger name="default">
    <level value="ALL"/>
  </logger>

  <root>
    <level value="ALL" />
    <appender-ref ref="RollingLogFileAppender" />
  </root>

  <appender name="RollingLogFileAppender" type="log4net.Appender.RollingFileAppender">
    <file value="..\Logs\\CurrentLog" />
    <appendToFile value="true" />
    <datePattern value="yyyyMMdd" />
    <rollingStyle value="Date" />
    <filter type="log4net.Filter.LevelRangeFilter">
      <acceptOnMatch value="true" />
      <levelMin value="INFO" />
      <levelMax value="FATAL" />
    </filter>
    <layout type="log4net.Layout.PatternLayout">
      <conversionPattern 
      value="%-5p %d %5rms %-22.22c{1} %-18.18M - %m%n" />
    </layout>
  </appender>
</log4net>
```

And also the declaration:

```
private static readonly ILog Log = LogManager.GetLogger("default");
```

Answer (score 1):

Actually, you haven't declared a logger in your config and it has wrong structure.
This is how it should look like:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<log4net>
    <logger name="Logger">
        <level value="ALL" />
        <appender-ref ref="RollingFileAppender"/>
    </logger>
    <appender name="RollingLogFileAppender"  type="log4net.Appender.RollingFileAppender">
        <file value="..\Logs\\CurrentLog" />
        <appendToFile value="true" />
        <datePattern value="yyyyMMdd" />

        <rollingStyle value="Date" />
        <filter type="log4net.Filter.LevelRangeFilter">
            <acceptOnMatch value="true" />

            <levelMin value="INFO" />
            <levelMax value="FATAL" />
        </filter>

        <layout type="log4net.Layout.PatternLayout">
            <conversionPattern 
            value="%-5p %d %5rms %-22.22c{1} %-18.18M - %m%n" />
        </layout>
    </appender>
</log4net>
```

Now you can access it this way:

```
private static readonly ILog Log = LogManager.GetLogger("Logger");
```

It definitely works.

Now about your code snippet. I'm not sure about your initialization. I haven't worked with log4net this way:

```
private static readonly ILog Log = LogManager.GetLogger(MethodBase.GetCurrentMethod().DeclaringType);
```

However, you can try declaring logger in `root` and initialize it:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<log4net>
    <root>
        <level value="ALL" />
        <appender-ref ref="RollingFileAppender"/>
    </root>
    <appender name="RollingLogFileAppender"  type="log4net.Appender.RollingFileAppender">
        <file value="..\Logs\\CurrentLog" />
        <appendToFile value="true" />
        <datePattern value="yyyyMMdd" />

        <rollingStyle value="Date" />
        <filter type="log4net.Filter.LevelRangeFilter">
            <acceptOnMatch value="true" />

            <levelMin value="INFO" />
            <levelMax value="FATAL" />
        </filter>

        <layout type="log4net.Layout.PatternLayout">
            <conversionPattern 
            value="%-5p %d %5rms %-22.22c{1} %-18.18M - %m%n" />
        </layout>
    </appender>
</log4net>

// ...
private static readonly ILog Log = LogManager.GetLogger(MethodBase.GetCurrentMethod().DeclaringType);
```

Comment: thank you. i change the structure just like you said(i just change the <file value="..\Logs\\CurrentLog" /> to     <file value="D:\Log\Log.txt" />) and define the log. but still the log.txt file doesn't created yet!

Comment: @user3351747 Did you check the file system permissions on the folder where you want to create the .log file?